# like button migration

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph, feed

With the news of the like button migration, it seems we won't be able to publish updates to users news feed.

[facebook like button migration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/migration/)

This was one of the best features ever released.. i.e. Liking / sharing your page and becoming your websites fan/follower in click. Anyone know how to accomplish this from now on.. is there anything new in the OpenGraph API to get this done in one user click.. I hope so.. I really need this functionality. I don't believe that Open graph technology is going backwards.